# If preview package connot work together with animate, how do you test the code fragment efficiently in the development phase?

Tags: best-practices

Making sub-files, that are compiled separately, not only helps reducing the compilation time for the main input file but also helps us to separately test the sub-file in the development phase. Sub-files often use `preview` package to produce tight PDF images that will be imported later from within the main input file.

From my experience, `preview` package cannot work together with `animate` package.
Shortly speaking, is there a good way to separately test code fragments with `animate` package loaded? Putting these code fragments in the main input file seems a bad strategy because during the development phase you will waste much time to compile them. Separating each of them in a `not-standalone` as follows

```
% shrinking.tex
\animateinline[palindrome,autoplay]{10}
\multiframe{11}{r=1+-0.1}{%
\pspicture(2,2)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red,opacity=0.5](1,1){\r}
\endpspicture}
\endanimateinline
```

and importing it later in the main input file can work. But the question is, how do you compile `shrinking.tex` during the development phase to get a tight paper size? You might think why do you need a tight paper size in the development phase if the imported PDF animate will no longer work. OK. It is my personal restriction that does not make sense of course!

Comment: In your main document, you could use `draft` as document or animate package option and `final` as local command option for the animation you are currently working on. Perhaps, this saves some time, at least for the dvips and ps2pdf steps.

Comment: @Alexander: Which method will produce faster animation viewed on Adobe Reader, `animateinline` or `animategraphics`?

Comment: They seem to produce identical results (I used the `measure` option for getting the FPS). The PDF file structure is similar for both. Some differences (in the file structure) result from using different drivers (dvips/ps2pdf vs. pdftex) but they don't impinge on animation performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this document with

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-pdf,pstricks,multido}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=1.0+-0.1}{11}{%
\pspicture(2,2)
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red,opacity=0.5](1,1){\r}
\endpspicture}}

\end{document}

latex <file>
dvips <file>
ps2pdf <file>.ps
```

then create a new document and use with pdflatex `\animategraphics[controls,loop]{5}{<file>}{}{}`. Here is an example of such a document: http://latex.userpage.fu-berlin.de/animate.pdf`

Comment: I will test it now. Whether it is what I am looking for.

Comment: I think I don't need `pst-pdf` because it internally invokes `preview`.

Comment: but then you have to use `\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}`